# Can a zfs mirror contain combined disks?

Tags: zfs

Can I create a single zfs mirror by combining disks?

```
mypool
    mirror1
        disk1 (2TB)
        disk2 (2TB)
        combined
            disk3 (1TB)
            disk4 (1TB)
```

In other words disk3 and disk4 should contain the same data as disk3+disk4 combined.

Is this possible? Or is something similar possible? If so, what are the commands that get me from my current configuration:

```
mypool
    mirror1
        disk1 (2TB)
        disk2 (2TB)
```

to the above configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but no, I don't think you can.

But if you're keen on experimenting, First

**BACK UP YOUR POOL!**

This post is an academic exercise designed to give you ideas, and carries no assurance that it will work in the real world, and you are explicitly cautioned against incurring data loss caused by actions you take based on these suggestions.

I do know for certain that `zpool` will warn you against mixing mirrored and raidz vdevs.  See the `-f` flag of `zpool add` for example.  Your proposed vdev `combined` is essentially a "`raidz-0`" or concatenated vdev, while `mirror1` is obviously a mirror.

With all that said, **after you've backed up your pool,** study the man page closely and note the `-n` flags on some commands.  That will allow you to see what the effect of a command will be without actually doing anything to your pool.

Futher evidence in the case against your solution **as proposed** is found in the `zpool` man page:

> Virtual devices cannot be nested, so a mirror or raidz virtual device
>   can only contain files or disks. Mirrors of mirrors (or other
>   combinations) are not allowed.

**However**, if you are on FreeBSD you can use `gstripe` to concatenate `disk3` and `disk4` to create the `combined` device.  You can then add that device to the mirror, since ZFS will see it as just another disk.

Here's a suggestion on how to experiment with this, assuming that you're running ZFS on FreeBSD.  We'll use simulated drives of 2GB instead of TB, but other than that....

```
# mkdir zfs-test; cd zfs-test
# truncate -s 2G drive1; truncate -s 2G drive2
# truncate -s 1G drive3; truncate -s 1G drive4
```

Create pseudo-devices md1 through md4 corresponding to the drive[1-4] files:

```
# for N in $(jot 4); do mdconfig -u $N -t vnode -f drive$N; done
# mdconfig -lv
md1     vnode    2048M  /home/jim/zfs-test/drive1
md2     vnode    2048M  /home/jim/zfs-test/drive2
md3     vnode    1024M  /home/jim/zfs-test/drive3
md4     vnode    1024M  /home/jim/zfs-test/drive4
```

Your existing mirror is simple to create:

```
# zpool create mypool mirror md1 md2
# zpool status mypool
  pool: mypool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        mypool      ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            md1     ONLINE       0     0     0
            md2     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Here is where you are currently stuck.  With this sandbox, you could now experiment with various commands using `zpool`'s `-n` flag, but I don't think anything will work, except this:

```
# gstripe label -h combined md3 md4
# gstripe status
           Name  Status  Components
stripe/combined      UP  md3
                         md4
# zpool attach mypool md2 stripe/combined
cannot attach stripe/combined to md2: device is too small
```

That is likely to happen to you, also, if your 2TB drives are **exactly** double the size of the 1TB drives.  The slight space loss in concatenating the two 1TB drives results in a `combined` drive slightly smaller than either of the two native 2TB drives.  `diskinfo(8)` confirms that `md1` and `md2` each have 4194304 sectors, but `stripe/combined` is 256 sectors smaller, at only 4194048:

```
# diskinfo -v md1 md2 stripe/combined
md1
        512             # sectorsize
        2147483648      # mediasize in bytes (2.0G)
        4194304         # mediasize in sectors
        0               # stripesize
        0               # stripeoffset
        MD-DEV5473951480393710199-INO24 # Disk ident.
        Yes             # TRIM/UNMAP support
        Unknown         # Rotation rate in RPM

md2
        512             # sectorsize
        2147483648      # mediasize in bytes (2.0G)
        4194304         # mediasize in sectors
        0               # stripesize
        0               # stripeoffset
        MD-DEV5473951480393710199-INO24 # Disk ident.
        Yes             # TRIM/UNMAP support
        Unknown         # Rotation rate in RPM

stripe/combined
        512             # sectorsize
        2147352576      # mediasize in bytes (2.0G)
        4194048         # mediasize in sectors
        65536           # stripesize
        0               # stripeoffset
        No              # TRIM/UNMAP support
        Unknown         # Rotation rate in RPM
```

But in my play sandbox, I can fix that problem.

First, I'll blow away the `combined` stripe and its component psuedo-devices /dev/md3 and /dev/md4:

```
# gstripe destroy combined
# mdconfig -d -u3; mdconfig -d -u4
# mdconfig -lv
md1     vnode    2048M  /home/jim/zfs-test/drive1
md2     vnode    2048M  /home/jim/zfs-test/drive2
```

Now I can re-create disk3 and disk4 to make them each slightly larger than 1GB, re-create the /dev/md3 and md4 devices, stripe them together to create the /dev/stripe/combined device, and attach that device to the mirror:

```
# truncate -s 1025M drive3
# truncate -s 1025M drive4
# mdconfig -u3 -t vnode -f drive3
# mdconfig -u4 -t vnode -f drive4
# gstripe label -h combined md3 md4
# zpool attach mypool md2 stripe/combined
# zpool status mypool
  pool: mypool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 81.5K in 0 days 00:00:04 with 0 errors on Thu May 23 15:27:26 2019
config:

        NAME                 STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        mypool               ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0           ONLINE       0     0     0
            md1              ONLINE       0     0     0
            md2              ONLINE       0     0     0
            stripe/combined  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: Wow, I must say that is an extensive answer! Your insight is very much appreciated. With this info in mind however I suppose I will buy another 2TB drive instead, especially since I'm on macos in this case... Thank you.